# How to compute $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}(e^{-1/x}-1)$?

Tags: limits

I need to compute $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}(e^{-1/x}-1)$$ using L'Hôpital's rule. Please hint me how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac1x=h$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^{-h}-1}{\sqrt h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{e^h-1}h\cdot\frac{\lim_{h\to0^+}\sqrt h}{-\lim_{h\to0^+}e^h}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}(e^{-\dfrac{1}{x}}-1)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(e^{-\dfrac{1}{x}}-1)}{\frac1{\sqrt{x}}}$$

Comment: I took $3$ derivatives and still have $\dfrac{0}{0}$

Comment: @jack,simplify after the first derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need l'Hôpital's theorem: if you use $t=1/x$, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{\sqrt{t}}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}\sqrt{t}
$$
and the limit of the fraction is the derivative of $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ at zero, which is $-e^{0}=-1$. So the limit is $0$.

With l'Hôpital's rule without substitutions, you need to do some algebra:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}(e^{-1/x}-1)=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x^{-1}}-1}{x^{-1/2}}
\overset{(\mathrm{H})}{=}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x^{-1}}(-x^{-2})}{(-1/2)x^{-3/2}}
$$
Simplify and you're done.

Comment: It's my task to solve it using only L'Hôpital's rule...